# How to determine the title of the website that Facebook will share

Tags: facebook, web, clone, share

How do you make a custom title for sharing the website on facebook?
My website is a clone of a random simple design i found online. 
Here is my

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Philosophy Page" />
<title>SanRuza</title>

<meta property="og:title" content="Sanruza" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="http://www.sanruza.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.sanruza.com/Logo.jpg" />

<meta name="author" content="Kapo Faris +43 664 316 324 9"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1050, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webfonts.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://sanruza.com/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="image_src" href="" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/color.js"></script>
</head>
```

I've checked the entire code and i don't see why isn't my website's name shown when i share it.

Comment: What is shown when you share your website?

Comment: The name of the website i cloned from.

Comment: Yes - please write me the name in letters.

Comment: And in your code is a title tag `<title>SanRuza</title>`. What about set there your title name?

Comment: Then you have to do a `?x` behind your share url, so that facebook will scratch your site again. Because atm your data is in their cache system.

Comment: Well there is a chance i shared my website on facebook before i updated meta"og:title". But even after i put in ?x it's still a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your bug.

I went on [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) page and entered your web url. Then facebook rescraped your website and got the correct title. As I mentioned in the comments it was a cache problem.

Hint: A few months ago it was possible to let facebook rescrape if you add some get parameters - but this obviously will not work anymore.